# Sentry 2 Relations with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Hello i have sentry2 package installed and i created a function for get the user by username even if i have like main column for login the email but it throw me an error.

So i created my model User and extend it with `\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User`

Then i set up a relations with another model in this case `Player`

So the relation look like this:

**User Model**

```
class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function sport() {

        return $this->hasOne('Core\Team\Player\Models\Player','player_id');
    }

}
```

**Player Model**

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','player_id');
    }
```

Then this is the function that find users by username giving me a error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sport()

**Function to get users by Username**

```
public function byUsername($username) {

        $emptyModelInstance = $this->sentry->getUserProvider()->getEmptyUser();
        $myUser = $emptyModelInstance->with('sport')->where('username', '=', $username)->first();

        if ( is_null($myUser) ) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return $myUser;
        }

    }
```

Ps: if i remove the with() method it work well

Comment: You're question could have been worded a little more clearly but I dont think it deserves a downvote +1 to get you back in the black. @downvoter - you could take some time to explain your downvote to be a bit more constructive

Answer (score 0):

I've got to be honest, I'm really unclear what you are trying to achieve here and I've never used the sentry package so this is a bit of a stab in the dark, but...

When you say "if i remove the with() method it work well" can you access the sport model if you remove the with().

e.g.

```
$myUser = $emptyModelInstance->where('username', '=', $username)->first();
dd($myUser->sport);
```

Does the above dump out your sport object?

If not then I suspect what is happening is that Sentry is using its own user model rather than the one you have defined so the sport() method is not available. you can confirm this by dd'ing the user and seeing what class it is an instance of.

If this is the case, a quick google search suggests that all you have to is publish the configs for the package and set your custom user model in there.

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11048

Failing this try adding a dump of you're user object to the question, might help work out whats going on.